# Finding data source for sql server connection in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

trying to connect to sql server from c#, using the format

```
    private void ConnectToSQL() 
    {    
        string connectionString = @"Data Source= ____;Initial Catalog=____;User ID=_____;Password=_____";    
        using (SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection (connectionString))    
        {        
           try {            
               objSqlConnection.Open();            
               objSqlConnection.Close();            
               Response.Write("Connection is successfull");        
           } 
           catch (Exception ex) 
           {           
               Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message.ToString());        
           }    
        }
     }
```

how do I find what the data source and initial catalogue are from management studio.  Having trouble establishing a connection.

Comment: Data source is the server instance you connect to and the initial catalog is the name of the database.

Answer (score 4):

`Data source` is the name of the MS SQL server instance you are connecting to and `Inital Catalog` is the database name you want to connect to.

**EG:** You have a default instance of MS SQL server Express and a database named Northwind.

The datasource would be `.\SQLEXPRESS` (the "." stands for the local machine) and the inital catalog would be `Northwind`

---

A very useful resource [Connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 3):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7e276c4-7d7d-4f37-bbbe-4a97e500b9b2/connection-string-in-c

It shows how to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`. Then if you get the parts right, it will make a well-constructed connection string for you when you call `builder.ConnectionString`.

One tripping point is if you are not using the default instance. If you use a named SQL Server instance, you need `servername\instancename` to identify the instance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get it from SSMS.

You can get it from Visual Studio, however. From the main menu,

View -> Server Explorer.

Expand Data Connections.

Add a connection to your server.

After adding the connection, right-click on the connection -> Properties.

There is a Connection String property that you can copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this in localhost you can use this

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db_name;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and your code

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ToString()))
{}
```